# What is the fastest OCR program?

Tags: osx, pdf, ocr

What program is quickest at processing and writing OCR information? The source file is a PDF, which I want to turn into a searchable PDF.

I am okay with sacrificing some accuracy at the expense of speed.

I prefer OS X applications.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanting to work with lightning fast OCR recognition on your Mac then you should check out the [LEADTOOLS OCR](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/leadtools-ocr/id604393629?mt=12) app for OS X. The LEADTOOLS OCR engine is one of the fastest character recognition engines and the linked application is a demo of it. The OCR engine can also be optimized for faster speeds with enhancements using various image processing commands which will result in better recognition as well which you can read about [here](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/to/leadtools.topics.forms.ocr~fo.topics.preprocessingimagesforocr.html).

If you are a software developer who wants to develop software with this engine, the full source of the linked OCR application along with the libraries can be obtained by downloading an evaluation of the toolkit [here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=main). The download will come with demos and will also include the source code to make modifications to them if needed  and is available on multiple platforms including MacOS, Android, iOS, Windows, Linux, and JavaScript.

Disclaimer: I am an employee of this product

Comment: While LEADTOOLS may have a fast character recognition engine, this application does not perform the desired function. That is, LEADTOOLS does not actually write the text to the PDF file. It outputs the text to a separate .txt file. I made my desire clear in my post: *"The source file is a PDF, which I want to turn into a searchable PDF."*